# Import .so file into MAUI

Tags: android, maui

I tried several ways to import a .so file into my project in Maui, in all cases it gives the error:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'nativeCreateCamera'
```

This is a code example i am trying to import:

```
public class NativeLibs
 {
  private const string Library = "libmlcamera-2.5.so";
  private long mNativePtr = nativeCreateCamera(); // The error occurs here
  [DllImport(Library, EntryPoint = "nativeCreateCamera", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  private static extern long nativeCreateCamera();
 }
```

I have imported the .so files in Platforms/Android/Resources/lib/arm.../libmlcamera-2.5.so

Also i have instanciated in csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedNativeLibrary Include="Platforms/Android/Resources/lib/arm64-v8a/libmlcamera-2.5.so"/>
    <EmbeddedNativeLibrary Include="Platforms/Android/Resources/lib/armeabi-v7a/libmlcamera-2.5.so"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

What i am doing wrong?